# python xgboost continue training on existing model

Tags: python, xgboost

Lets say I build an xgboost model:

```
bst = xgb.train(param0, dtrain1, num_round, evals=[(dtrain, "training")])
```

Where:

- param0 is a set of params to xgb,
- dtrain1 is a DMatrix ready to be trained
- num_round is the number of rounds

Then, I save the model to disk:

```
bst.save_model("xgbmodel")
```

Later on, I want to reload the model I saved and **continue** training it with dtrain2

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't even have to manually load the model from the disk and retrain.

All you need to do is the same `xgb.train` command with additional parameter: xgb_model= (either xgboost model full path name you've saved like in the question or a Booster object).

Example:

```
bst = xgb.train(param0, dtrain2, num_round, evals=[(dtrain, "training")], xgb_model='xgbmodel')
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

For users who are looking to continue training with `XGBClassifier` or object obtained from `.fit` function of `sklearn`.

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

# best_est = best number of tree
# best_lr = best learning days
# best_subsample = best subsample bw 0 and 1

params = {'objective': 'binary:logistic', 'use_label_encoder': False, 
          'seed': 27, 'eval_metric': 'logloss', 'n_estimators': best_est, 
          'learning_rate': best_lr, 'subsample': best_subsample}

# train iteration 1  below

model = XGBClassifier(**params)
model.fit(x_train_1, y_train_1)

# train iteration 2 below

model = model.fit(x_train_2, y_train_2, xgb_model=model.get_booster())
```

In the above code
`x_train_*`, `y_train_*` are the object of pandas `DataFrame` type.

The main concept to learn here is, `xgb` core functions while retraining always takes the `booster` as input. So one can either provide the `booster` from model object or the `saved model path`.