# Re-train loaded model from pickle file

Tags: machine-learning, pickle, xgboost, training-data

I have three datasets: *train*, *validation*, *test* and I am currently using an XGBoost Classifier to do the job on a classification task.

I trained the **XGBClassifier** on the *train* set and saved it as a *pickle* file to avoid having to re-train it every time. Once I load the model from the pickle file, I am able to use the predict method from it, but I don't seem to be able to train this model on the validation set or any other new dataset.

Note: I do not get any error output, the jupyter lab cell looks like it's working perfectly, but my CPU cores are all resting during this cell's operation, so I see the model isn't being fitted.

Could this be a problem with XGBoost or pickle dumped models are not able to be fitted again after loading?

Comment: Do you want to continue training it from the point it stopped? (By creating more boosters)

Comment: @EranMoshe Yes, I've trained on *train* set, saved it and restarted jupyter kernel. Now I want to load the model and train it on *validation* set, making the model fitted both on train and validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same question a year ago, [You can find here the question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000253/python-xgboost-continue-training-on-existing-model/47000386#47000386)

Though, in this way, you will keep adding "trees" (boosters) to your existing model, using your new data.

It might be better to train a new model on your training + validation data sets.

Whatever you decide to do, you should try both options and evaluate your results to see what fits better for your data.

Comment: Perfect! Sorry, I couldn't find your question before, it really covers my problem! Thanks