# How to add extra 5k trees in xgb classification

Tags: classification, xgboost, xgbclassifier

I have run XGBClassification where I have used 5k trees -

model = XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.01,max_depth=2,
monotone_constraints=(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0),n_estimators=5000,objective='binary:logistic',verbosity=1,model_out='test_5k.pickle.dat')

Now I want to run the same model for 10k trees, but I don't want to run it from scratch because. with 5k trees, it took 24 hours. Is there any way I can use the old model & ask XGBC to run for the next 5k trees?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can I get this type of solution for XGBClassifier, as i already have started building my model in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python xgboost continue training on existing model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000253/python-xgboost-continue-training-on-existing-model)